# jEasyUI and JSON

Tags: json, gridview, subgrid

I am trying to use JEasyUI in my project to display a data grid which has a subgrid with a master grid feature.

My application calls a webservice which returns data on JSON format. I read tutorials from site but it was on php language.

Can any body please give example to use JSON result to populate data grid from JEasyUI?

It will be quite helpful if the entire process can be covered in jQuery/client side .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to this page?

http://jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid22.php

The PHP bit is not part of the jEasyUI page. As you can see, it ends in `echo json_encode($items);` and is an **external** script, only used in the `url` parameter of the jEasyUI setup.

So just ignore the PHP bit on the page and all the info is in there. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask.